What are some basic methods/algorithms for drawing wireframe shapes using Gizmos?
This is definitely a "doing for the sake of learning" question, so apologies in advance for that, but how would you go about using the Gizmos class to draw a basic wireframe shape?
I'm currently doing the following to try to draw a triangle:
private Transform[] points = new Transform[3];

private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    DrawPaths();
}

private void DrawPaths()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;

    Vector3 firstPoint = points[0].position;
    Vector3 secondPoint = points[1].position;
    Vector3 thirdPoint = points[2].position;

    Gizmos.DrawLine(firstPoint, secondPoint);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(secondPoint, thirdPoint);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(thirdPoint, firstPoint);
}

I'm certain that there must be better ways of accomplishing something like this, especially ones that aren't quite so explicit and ham-fisted, but I'm not necessarily experienced enough yet to know what those might look like, and I'm struggling to find resources which describe how it might be done (does no one else think it's anything worth knowing? are there resources that I'm not finding?).
There are things that I'm aware of in the Unity API, like Gizmos.DrawLineList() and Gizmos.DrawLineStrip(), which I imagine would probably do the job well enough, and which would probably be fine answers, but especially if those did not exist, how might you go about doing something like this?

You've already figured out the way to draw individual lines without using DrawLineList() or DrawLineStrip(). Why do you want to ignore those specific functions? What exactly are you trying to draw - a mesh?

I fear that you're either misunderstanding or not reading the question entirely. I'm not asking so much for a solution in the way you're suggesting--Gizmos.DrawMesh() also exists. I'm not specifically ignoring those functions, but all the same, I would like to know how I might accomplish drawing wireframes without continually typing the same lines over and over (see above code; what if I have more points?). It's not what I'm doing it for, but let's say that I'm trying to visualize a path in the editor that a GameObject should follow, and that the path happens to be a basic shape.

Presumably in that scenario you'd have a data structure somewhere with a list of points (or a function that calculates them). Iterate over the points/range and draw each line as needed?

@Basic could you elaborate on this somewhat, or perhaps provide a quick example?

I think I'm missing something or perhaps I wasn't clear... points = [/*Your list of points*/]; for(i=0;i<points.length-2;i++) {Drawline(points[i], points[i+1]);} (although I'm not sure why you'd do that rather than DrawLineList)

@Basic for some additional clarification, are you talking about using something along the lines of a List<Vector3> points? To your point in parentheses, it's really just to demystify the functionality of it. Doesn't really need to be practical; as stated above, it's more about "doing for the sake of learning," if that makes sense. And to clarify, I'm under the impression that there's more than one way to skin a cat, so to speak--if there's not, that's also fine, but I'd like to know.

Out-of-bound errors occur when you reference something beyond the length of an array. It could be direct (i.e. the array has 5 items & you try to get any greater than index 4) or indirect (i.e. you're passing an array to a method and it's not sized as expected). It's fine to ask about some other approach for the sake of learning. But if you're getting an out of bounds error that you can't debug, you're probably going to get further faster by asking about that (preferably with a verified minimal example) instead of trying elaborate work arounds.

You're asking me what tool I'd use for a problem you can't/won't define. Use the right tool for the job. If you want a series of straight lines, a list would be reasonable. If you want curves and line segments, maybe you store an array of point to use in a bezier and run them through a function, or perhaps nodes and control points. It all depends on what you're triyng to accomplish.

Okay, so three people now are saying that I'm failing to describe the problem at hand. I feel that I have done so, and I don't seem to be getting any constructive feedback on anything that might be missing necessary context.

@Pikalek the out-of-bounds error is no longer an issue; I've rectified that in the provided code. I'm still unaccustomed to StackExchange, so are people not able to see my edit notes?

Is the code that Basic shared in the comment above the kind of answer you're looking for? From what I understand from reading your question and the comment thread, that seems to do what you ask. If there's some specific way in which this is unsuitable for your needs, can you clarify how an answer should differ from this?

@DMGregory Yes, that is the sort of answer that I'm looking for--moreover, it would be good to know if there are other approaches which might work (though I obviously don't expect one person to address every single possibility; there are probably standard approaches for solving problems like this, though if there are not, or if other approaches would be considered unreasonable for whatever reason, I would also like to know that much, and why they might be unreasonable).

According to the timestamps my comment about about of bounds errors was made about 6 minutes before you made the edit to your question in which you removed the mention of the out of bounds error. It's possible that you might have been in the process of making the edit while I left the comment.

Using Gizmos, you can draw lines in different ways using the following commands:

Gizmos.DrawLine()
Gizmos.DrawLineList()
Gizmos.DrawWireCube()
Gizmos.DrawWireMesh()
Gizmos.DrawWireSphere()

It sounds like you want to be able to draw a complex wireframe without having to draw individual lines or using any of the helpful functions that Unity has provided for drawing complex wireframes without drawing individual lines. You can't do that. You could theoretically write your own function to simplify the process of drawing some shape made up of individual lines, but it would still have to draw the individual lines, and your custom function would probably end up doing the same thing as one of the built-in functions.
As for drawing a triangle specifically, you've already figured out what I would say is the best way to draw a triangle. If you wanted a more general function for drawing a series of points, it would look something like this:
public function DrawPath(List<Vector3> points, bool loop) {
    // Connect each point to the previous point
    for (int i = 1; i < points.Count; i++) {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(points[i], points[i - 1]);
    }
    if (loop) {
        // Connect last to first
        Gizmos.DrawLine(points[points.Count - 1], points[0]);
    }
}

If you're only trying to draw a triangle, that function is overkill because it has functionality you don't need. If you're trying to draw other kinds of paths, it could be useful, except that it's really completely unnecessary since you could just as easily use one of the built-in functions that does the same thing.

Some advice: don't invent unnecessary problems "for the sake of learning". Time that you spend trying to solve arbitrary hypothetical problems like this is time that you could have spent learning something useful or actually developing your game.

I mention right before the code that I'm trying to draw a triangle. I also mention that I'd like to apply some solution to other basic shapes before that. That in mind, I fail to see how or in what way I'm "refusing" to explain what it is that I'm trying to do. Constructive feedback would be appreciated.

@NJJ_002 You already know how to draw a triangle. There's no "better" way to draw a triangle. The algorithm for drawing other shapes  will depend on the shape and how you want to draw the shape. For example, you could draw a box by passing it eight vertices, or by passing it the center point and dimensions, or by passing it the min and max corners...

All the same, @Basic suggested that I might construct a list of points and then iterate over those points, rather than potentially type out Gizmos.DrawLine(somePoint, someNextPoint); over and over. And maybe that seems obvious, but it didn't occur to me to do that. More to the point of that, though, it seems like there's at least one other way to do what I'm trying to do. You say in your comment that there is no "better" way, and I would just like to address the fact that this also satisfies the question, to a degree, though knowing why there is no "better" way would also be helpful.

That approach works if you're drawing a series of points, each only connected to the next. It's not, for example, how you would draw a mesh (where you'd traverse the mesh for edges) or a circle (where you'd specify the center and radius and possibly number of edges, and use a circle drawing algorithm to draw the individual edges).

@NJJ_002 Part of the issue here is that, since you don't have a specific problem in mind ("I want to draw this specific shape without using the built-in functions") and instead have a vague hypothetical problem ("I want to draw any arbitrary shape without using the built-in functions"), you haven't thought through the details and don't realize how broad your question is.

And to your first point, that's really all that I'm doing and trying to find resources on-- "drawing a series of points, each only connected to the next"; didn't find those resources, ended up here on StackExchange. I'm not trying to draw a mesh, or a circle (at least not yet), or anything else more complicated than that. I left the terminology broad in the case of "basic shapes" in the event that there existed some sort of "catch-all" approach to shapes in general (i.e. if you can draw a triangle, then you can draw a square, then you can draw a pentagon, etc.).

@NJJ_002 I added an example function that does the same thing as DrawLineList() or DrawLineStrip() would do (though the former doesn't have the loop argument). It's also the same thing as Basic suggested, just with the loop argument added.
